# Segmentation Fault error when trying to compare two videos with pHash library and its ruby bindings

Tags: c++, ruby, ffmpeg, segmentation-fault, phash

I have set up my system with the latest ffmpeg and pHash libraries (ffmpeg-2.2.1 and pHash-0.9.6) as well as the pHash ruby gem (https://github.com/toy/pHash).

I am using ruby and attempting to compare two video files like this:

```
require 'phash/video'

video1 = Phash::Video.new('video1.mp4')
video2 = Phash::Video.new('video2.mp4')

video1 % video2
```

Executing this script results in a Segmentation fault:

```
..../gems/pHash-1.1.4/lib/phash/video.rb:20: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.9.3p545 (2014-02-24 revision 45159) [x86_64-darwin13.1.0]

-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0008 p:---- s:0029 b:0029 l:000028 d:000028 CFUNC  :ph_dct_videohash
c:0007 p:0042 s:0024 b:0024 l:000023 d:000023 METHOD .../gems/pHash-1.1.4/lib/phash/video.rb:20
c:0006 p:0038 s:0017 b:0017 l:000016 d:000016 METHOD .../gems/pHash-1.1.4/lib/phash.rb:43
c:0005 p:0025 s:0014 b:0014 l:000013 d:000013 METHOD .../gems/pHash-1.1.4/lib/phash.rb:39
c:0004 p:0011 s:0011 b:0011 l:000010 d:000010 METHOD .../gems/pHash-1.1.4/lib/phash.rb:48
c:0003 p:0050 s:0006 b:0006 l:000128 d:0011b8 EVAL   video_test_phash.rb:3
c:0002 p:---- s:0004 b:0004 l:000003 d:000003 FINISH
c:0001 p:0000 s:0002 b:0002 l:000128 d:000128 TOP   

-- Ruby level backtrace information ----------------------------------------
video_test_phash.rb:3:in `<main>'
.../gems/pHash-1.1.4/lib/phash.rb:48:in `similarity'
.../gems/pHash-1.1.4/lib/phash.rb:39:in `phash'
.../gems/pHash-1.1.4/lib/phash.rb:43:in `compute_phash'
.../gems/pHash-1.1.4/lib/phash/video.rb:20:in `video_hash'
.../gems/pHash-1.1.4/lib/phash/video.rb:20:in `ph_dct_videohash'

...

Abort trap: 6
```

It appears that the crash happens in the ph_dct_videohash function which is part of the pHash library. The function is in file pHash.cpp. I am copying it here in case it would make sense to someone:

```
ulong64* ph_dct_videohash(const char *filename, int &Length){

    CImgList<uint8_t> *keyframes = ph_getKeyFramesFromVideo(filename);
    if (keyframes == NULL)
    return NULL;

    Length = keyframes->size();

    ulong64 *hash = (ulong64*)malloc(sizeof(ulong64)*Length);
    CImg<float> *C = ph_dct_matrix(32);
    CImg<float> Ctransp = C->get_transpose();
    CImg<float> dctImage;
    CImg<float> subsec;
    CImg<uint8_t> currentframe;

    for (unsigned int i=0;i < keyframes->size(); i++){
    currentframe = keyframes->at(i);
    currentframe.blur(1.0);
    dctImage = (*C)*(currentframe)*Ctransp;
    subsec = dctImage.crop(1,1,8,8).unroll('x');
    float med = subsec.median();
    hash[i] =     0x0000000000000000;
    ulong64 one = 0x0000000000000001;
    for (int j=0;j<64;j++){
        if (subsec(j) > med)
        hash[i] |= one;
        one = one << 1;
    }
    }

    keyframes->clear();
    delete keyframes;
    keyframes = NULL;
    delete C;
    C = NULL;
    return hash;
}
```

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Does FFMPEG play the individual videos properly?

Comment: Yes, I am able to use FFPLAY to play the videos successfully and I am also able to use FFMPEG to transcode the videos to different formats without a problem.

Answer (score 1):

In the latest versions of ffmpeg, some functions (like "avformat_open_input" in this case) segfault when given an uninitialized pointer.  [Someone](http://lists.phash.org/pipermail/phash-support-phash.org/2013-January/000140.html) on the pHash support mailing list has shown how to modify the pHash source in order to initialize the pointers, and prevent the segfaults.

To fix the segmentation faults, lines 365 and 411 in `pHash-0.9.6/src/cimgffmpeg.cpp` must be changed from `AVFormatContext *pFormatCtx;` to `AVFormatContext *pFormatCtx = NULL;`, and then the source code must be recompiled and installed.

Note that there still seem to be some problems with video hashes: for example, many (non-.mp4) video formats are unsupported, and cause segmentation faults.